# Executable python script does not produce output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this python script

```
#!/Users/usr/anaconda3/bin/python
with open('test.txt','w+') as file:
    file.write('string')
```

that I made executable for an automation task by doing

```
chmod a+x test.py
```

I then converted it to a ".command" script. It is supposed to output a text file but I dont see anything in my directory.

Any comments is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be running it in another directory.

Comment: Can you write log file as well to check the errors , if any ?

Comment: could you please run 'which python' to see that the you're indeed pointing to an existing version of python?

Comment: @DYZ It was outputting to my home directory for some reason. Thanks. Not sure how to make this question as answered tho.